# Can I connect two monitors to my HP laptop?

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, cpu, hdmi

I have [HP 14s-cf3 laptop](https://store.hp.com/in-en/default/hp-laptop-14s-cf3006tu-3r496pa.html).

I want to know if I can connect two external monitors to this laptop. I am able to connect one external monitor through HDMI port. Can I connect another monitor to type C port? I want two different screens appear on these two monitors, not the same screen mirrored on these two monitors.

I checked processor i3 - 1005G1 and [intels page says](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196588/intel-core-i3-1005g1-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html), it supports 3 displays. But how do I know if laptop motherboard and ports dont form any restriction on connecting two external monitors and that I can indeed connect 2nd external monitor to type C port?

If not through type C port, what other options I have for connecting two external monitor.

Comment: The linked description does not mention anything about display signals or alternate mode on the USB-C port. Only specially prepared USB-C ports can be used for attaching a monitor.

Comment: I myself have done this with another HP model. 1 monitor to HDMI, another to USB3 -> HDMI and it worked for me just fine.  I have a different HP but I bet it will work.  USB -> HDMI adapters are cheap enough to roll the dice and find out.

Comment: @Robert , as a display port.. sure.. but there are plenty of adapters that provide USB->HDMI support (howbeit slower than what you speak) that work just fine.  I own three of them and they even work on old USB2 ports (again.. slow but work).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas are you talking about USB-A port or USB-C port? Also I never come across anything that will convert videos signal from USB-A to HDMI. Can you please give me link to such adapter? Also will it work even when specs does not speak about display signals and alternate mode of those USB ports (as suggested by Robert)?

Comment: @Maha  Here's some adapters for USB-A to HDMI:  https://www.displaylink.com/products/find?vid_hdmi=1&usba=1  These adapters do not require an alternate mode capable port, which is meaningless with USB-A anyway.  The adapters contain a GPU of their own and so are not dependent on the video capability of the host computer.

Comment: Seems that there are no one selling DisplayLink adapters in my country . Can we run some software and find whether USB C supports display signal before buying any adapter?
Can we connect one display through cable and another through wireless (say Miracast) connection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a USB C hub? A hub or dock reduces the number of cables you need to deal with when you connect and remove your laptop! Be careful to check the speed requirements that the hub needs and your board supports, and watch out for thunderbolt docks as they look the same but aren't.

EDIT

As StarCat clarified below, a port replicator supporting multiple display out over usb is what I *intended* to recommend. Many devices called 'hubs' will just one to one, and will only support a single display out on that usb port, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: How does this answer to the question?

Comment: I have just such a hub which has an HDMI out @StarCat.  It works great for programming but I wouldn't try to game on it.

Comment: Ok, so you mean a port replicator (with HDMI and possibly other outputs like ethernet) and not a simple “one-port-to-many-of-the-same-ports” hub? That was not entirely clear from your answer. But I agree that might be a solution.

Comment: Port replicator is a much more precise name thank you! Bad habit form my old job, we called everything a 'hub'

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get an additional monitor port is via the
USB-C port.

Unfortunately, the
[14s-cf3006tu manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06243005.pdf)
says this about all the USB-C ports: "provide high-speed data transfer".

This means that your ports do not support Alternate mode and cannot
connect directly to the monitor.

You will need to use a cable that has a display adapter built-in,
although do not expect this adapter to be of high quality.
The cable will be of type "USB-C to port-type", for whatever the
input port-type is of your monitor.